# Как представить в БД состояние сущности

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, orm

Есть одна бизнес сущность. Она представлена на entity Order. У заказа есть несколько состояний. это open -> inprogress -> closed.

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли посредством hibernate реализовать данные отношения?

- когда у Order состояние open тогда нам разрешено вносить update.

Comment: А в чем собственно сложность?

Comment: @Никита Возможно имеется ввиду как правильно реализовать это: с вынесением в отдельную таблицу или в коде прописывать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ВОЗМОЖНО у меня ошибка в коде ниже. Я не тестировал удаление объектов, поэтому перед добавлением кода в программу убедитесь в ее правильности. На [данном сайте](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) рассказано как правильно добавлять:

```java
@OneToMany(
          mappedBy = "orderStatus",
          cascade = {
                  CascadeType.MERGE,
                  CascadeType.PERSIST
          },
          orphanRemoval = true
    )
```

Как вариант:

#### Order.java:

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Data
@Table
public class Order {

    /* некоторый код */

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="orderStatus_id")
    private OrderStatus orderStatus;
}
```

#### OrderStatus.java

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Data
@Table
public class OrderStatus {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "orderStatus_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="orderStatus_generator", sequenceName = "seq_orderStatus", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    /* некоторый код */

    @OneToMany(
          mappedBy = "orderStatus",
          cascade = {
                  CascadeType.MERGE,
                  CascadeType.PERSIST
          },
          orphanRemoval = true
    )
    List<OrderStatus> orderStatuses = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addOrderStatus(OrderStatus orderStatus) {
        orderStatuses.add(orderStatus);
        orderStatus.setOrderStatus(this);
    }

    public void removeOrderStatus(OrderStatus orderStatus) {
        orderStatuses.remove(orderStatus);
        orderStatus.setOrderStatus(null);
    }
```

В папке `resources` рядом с файлом-конфигуратором (`application.properties`) создаем файл `data.sql` и в нем пишем следующее:

```sql
REPLACE INTO `orderStatus` VALUES (1,'Open');
REPLACE INTO `orderStatus` VALUES (2,'In progress');
REPLACE INTO `orderStatus` VALUES (3,'Closed');
REPLACE INTO `seq_orderStatus` VALUE (4);
```